# How can I set the chapter titles in EB Garamond?

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

I am using the font EB Garamond but I don't succeed to get the chapter and section titles to be set right. The package `ebgaramond` does not have all the features I want, and when looking for the font with fontspec, the true type version seems to be taken. That's why I have to define the path to the fonts explicitly.

At the moment, I use the following MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: yes, options: -synctex=-1 }

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{%
    ,RawFeature={+dlig, +calt, +cv11, +ss05}
    ,Ligatures={TeX}
}
\setmainfont[%
    ,Path = C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/
    ,Extension = .otf
    ,UprightFont = *12-Regular
    ,ItalicFont  = *12-Italic
    ,BoldFont = *08-Regular
]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
Test
\section{Test}
%\textin{T}est % This does not work eather.

\end{document}
```

I don't know, what is happening and would like to use the font in all places.

Comment: `scrreport` is responsible for determining what font is used in section and chapter headings, not `fontsepc`.  It is explained in the manual; something like `\setkomafont{chapter}{<commands>}`, if I remember...

Comment: Thanks, will look at that. Actually, the headings work correctly. And the page numbers also. Weird. Only the titles are misbehaving.

Comment: What is a 'title' in the above example?

Comment: `\chapter{Test}`. Egregs answer seems to work. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard for the Koma-Script classes is to print sectional titles in the sans serif font. Adding

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

to your preamble should suffice.

Please, don't use Bold Garamond: it's like actors wearing a wristwatch in a movie about ancient Romans.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But the titles are set bold now. Should I turn that off? And how? Could you please make the initial working? Don't want to open a new question for that cosmetic. Thank you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Just don't load a bold font. Or add also `\mdseries` after `\rmfamily`

Comment: @egreg: Nice comparison!