# Garamond font with LaTeX

Tags: fonts, licensing, ebgaramond

Is there any package that allows to use Garamond font with LaTeX documents that are generated with `pdflatex`?

If so:

1. Does this package allow to use font for commercial purposes for free?
2. If not, is there any other way to use that font for commercial purposes with LaTeX document? If so, where license could be obtained for it?

I thnk [ebgaramond](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond) package meets my criteria, but I am not sure.

Comment: Your linked CTAN package page states that `ebgaramond` is subject to [The SIL Open Font License (OFL)](http://www.ctan.org/license/ofl), which states: "The OFL al­lows the li­censed fonts to be used, stud­ied, mod­i­fied and re­distributed freely as long as they are not sold by them­selves." So as long as you are not selling the font itself, you are OK.

Comment: Anything in TeX Live *should* be OK although it is always worth checking the licence to be sure. (But if it turns out not to be OK, you should let the TeX Live people know.) http://ctan.org/pkg/garamondx is probably OK, too, provided you only want to use the font and not distribute it.(E.g. you want to use it to typeset a book you'll sell rather than writing a commercial software application which will include it.)

Comment: Note, however, that we cannot give legal advice and that the comments here are merely opinions provided 'as is'. You should obtain qualified legal advice for the relevant jurisdiction(s) if required.

Answer (score 4):

I am going through the motions of this now, and Yes, the ebgaramond package provides this interesting font. 
 The only issue I am having with it is that it lacks a bold font.
This is not necessarily a bad thing as exemplified by Egregs comments in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161675/4621

There are solutions to 'the bold problem' which I am working through now, only because I am retrofitting a document. The solution is given here: [EBGaramond Bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168789/4621)

The [Licensing](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) as laid out by the author is:

> EB Garamond is free software under the terms of the SIL Open Fonts
>   License (ofl). That means, you are entitled to do what you want to
>   with these fonts, as long as you
>
> - retain the ofl notice, even if you distribute it in a modified form
> - don’t sell them on their own
> - don’t claim they were your work.

There is no pdf manual as such, and I am still confused by some of the terms, still, blind leading the blind here is a MWE to get you started. Lining gives me proper numbers again.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\author{\swshape Authors Illustrious Name}
\title{Title}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{In the Beginning}
\lipsum[2]
Some numbers and interesting ligatures ff, ffi, st, 123456789

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\author{Authors Illustrious Name}
\title{Title}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{In the Beginning}
\blindtext
Some numbers and interesting ligatures ff, ffi, st, 123456789
\blindmathpaper
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am digging out this question to showcase a somewhat different approach, although similar to [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179883/142180): `garamondx`. It's an URW Garamond, licensed under AFPL, which [means](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) commercial use is allowed. You'd need to install it with `getnonfreefonts`.

I used a somewhat elaborate setup of:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[swashQ]{garamondx}
\usepackage[supstfm=NewG8-sups]{superiors}
```

[image: screenshot]